# retrofit with spring, declared a typedfile param but expects a MultiPartfile Param

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, retrofit

I'm new to retrofit and spring, and I have an error in implementation based on examples:

I have an interface declared as follows:

```
public interface ImageApi {

  @Multipart
  @POST("/image/{id}/data")
  public boolean setImageData(@Path("id") long id, @Part("data") TypedFile imageData);

}
```

An a spring controller that implements the ImageApi interface:

```
public class ImageController implements ImageApi {

  @RequestMapping(value="/image/{id}/data")
    public @ResponseBody boolean setImageData(@PathVariable long id, MultipartFile  imageData) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The compiler show me an error because I have a variable "imageData" with type MultipartFile
in the controller, but expects a TypedFile variable. However the examples have this form of implementation.

Please, tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the full stack trace/error the compiler is giving you.

Comment: thanks, i'm not sure if i must implements the interface. i believe tha i'm misunderstand the retrofit usage. The eclipse IDE show an error because the class doesnt implements a method with the correct signature

Answer (score 1):

You only have to remove 'implements ImageApi' from the controller.

The interface is annotated with Retrofit annotations in order to communicate with the service (from the client side).

The controller (at the server side) have to support the HTTP API described by the interface, but should not implement this interface in a 'Java sense' (you should not have ImageController implements ImageApi).